# Spring Kafka transactional consumer only

Tags: java, spring, transactions, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Referring to [spring-kafka doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/htmlsingle/#_transactional_listener_container) seems that is possible to configure a listener container to bind offset commit to a transaction.
Since this paragraph is reported under [Producer section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/htmlsingle/#_sending_messages), from the context I can desume that configuring the listener container transactionally is a way to perform validation of producer transaction before committing it.

What about consuming only? Is it possible to use kafkamessagelistenercontainer (configured with kafkatransactionmanager) to commit offset of consumed messages transactionally? I suppose no, because kafkaproducer and kafkaconsumer are not same api

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve.

The intent of transactions in Kafka is that any producer sends and consumer offset commits are atomic (all in or all out).

The container does not know whether the listener actually published any messages so it will work the same (send the consumer offsets to the transaction) regardless.

If you want to publish some messages which are **not** part of the transaction, you can do so by using a `KafkaTemplate` with a different (non-transactional) producer factory. That way, the template will not find the transaction's producer and use one from the second producer factory. If the transaction rolls back, the published messages will not.

**EDIT**

If the listener container is configured with some other transaction manager (other than a `KafkaTransactionManager`, including a chained transaction manager) then the container can't send the offsets to the transaction since it can't access the transaction's `Producer`. You could use a `KafkaTemplate` to send the offset to the transaction within your listener; it will use the transaction's producer.

However, there are two ways to do what you want.

1. Configure the container with a `KTM` and annotate you listener with `@Transactional` - using the DB TxM - for a normal case the DB tx will commit and the the container will commit. For a failure, the DB will rollback and the Kafka TX will roll back.
2. Don't use a Kafka TM and configure the [new `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/_reference.html#_seek_to_current_container_error_handlers) and the container will replay the failed delivery if the listener throws an exception.

Comment: I have a microservice that is only consumer. The main goal is to have a way to bind consumer offset commit policy to outcome of a database transaction. I'm now understanding that transactional support refers only to distributed kafka transaction between producer and consumer. It's so correct to assert that consumer committing offset produces the outcome of the transaction (success or rollback)? Can I use a chained transaction manager (kafka +dB) also for a microservice that is consumer only, taking care to manually call sendconsumeroffset on kafkatemplate as stated by doc?

Comment: @GaryRussell I am also working on the similar use case and as per your second comment, if we go for SeekToCurrentErrorHandler for handling exceptions then again there is a possibility of getting some exception while performing DB tx. In such a case I need to roll back the entire transaction. So my question is, if we follow the second comment, again I need to use Transactional annotation on both the layers i.e. on the listener and on DB layer as well. correct? Also, since I have configured dead letter topic for failed messages, will it commit the offset for those msg in the actual topic or not?

Comment: Don't ask questions in comments to old answers, especially when they are over a year old. Frameworks evolve; new features are added all the time; the answer might be different now. Ask a new question with precise details of what you want to achieve. You should not need to use `@Transactional` on the listener, ever.